# Upcoming event script

Tags: php, mysql, events, show

I am trying to make a script which shows upcoming event (single one).

Here is what I have:

Joomla, an extension where you can add an event and a calendar of that extension that shows those events on it. Events are stored in MySQL (date of event is stored xxx-xx-xx format).

To show an event till date I am thinking this:

```
<?php if(strtotime('gets date from mysql') > time()): ?>
```

And I face an issue here. How to tell a script what event to pick automaticaly, and after deadline to pick another, nearest event?

To find an event I think it has to search from this day and find the first one after today's date.

(edit: maybe it is better to use `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE 'time' > NOW() ORDER BY 'time' ASC LIMIT 1` instead of strtotime?)

Thank you!

Regards,
Baseckas

Comment: Yes, adjusting the MySQL query would be better.

Comment: I don't see wyhy your decision would be bad. Maybe there are hours set, when there can be couple of events in day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query like this to return your upcoming event:

```
SELECT * FROM EventTable
WHERE Date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY Date
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Comment: Can I ask why LIMIT is 0, 1 instead of just LIMIT 1?

Comment: you can also use limit 1. 0 is the default for the offset. i've put it like this to be more complete, in case you wanted the second upcoming event you'd replace 0 with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Select the date field as a datefield.

```
SELECT * FROM .. WHERE time >= CURDATE()
```